# How to cancel async http call?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, blazor-server-side

So, I have the following case:

A user makes async call from my front-end blazor (razor) component and invokes, for example:

```cs
var numbers = await numberService.GetAllNumbers();
```

But, while the operation is being completed the user decides to switch to another component, but still this API call is left running, although the user essentially does not need this information, anymore.

How can I terminate this API call or handle it's result gracefully. Because currently, I get `NullReferenceException`s, because the service which handles the received API response was disposed (because the blazor components get disposed once you switch to another one).

And the most important part that I missed is that I cannot modify the service methods. So I cannot pass cancellation tokens.

Comment: Pass a `CancellationToken` maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post. I forgot to mention that I cannot edit the http requests to pass new parameter. I am using legacy code.

Comment: Then what is your question if you can't change the code? `cancellationToken` is not passed from the HttpRequest, instead Blazor will inject it server-side

Comment: Can you give further info on this idea. Thank you.

Comment: If you have no way of cancelling the request then whatever process initiated it has to wait for it to complete.  Use a HttpContext factory and move the actual call to a backend service that doesn't get disposed, so can await it's completion.